# Selecting files with folder using QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, qfiledialog

I have a use case in an application using C++ and Qt (on windows 10). The application uses 7zip.exe as a subprocess to uncompress the files in a selected folder. I need to use QFileDialog to select a folder, and get all the files with extension .zip and .7z, to be selected automatically and then uncompress them using QProcess and display them in the output.
I came up with this code snippet. For selecting the files with selected folders.

```
void MainWindow::on_browseButton_clicked()
{
      QFileDialog d(this);
      d.setFileMode(QFileDialog::Directory);
      d.setNameFilter("*.zip");
      if (d.exec())
        qDebug () << d.selectedFiles();
}
```

but this code does not run, and it displays just the folder name not with no files selected. Could anyone suggest where I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: ***I need to use QFileDialog to select a folder, and get all the files with extension .zip and .7z, to be selected automatically and then uncompress them using QProcess and display them in the output.*** Are you sure you need a QFileDialog at all? I think you just want to enumerate the folder looking for .zip files.

Comment: I am new to qt, could you please suggest some code snippet how to do this.

Comment: @drescherjm That is incorrect. `QFileDialog::Directory` means the dialog will only allow the user to *select* a folder to return to the caller, but both files and folders are *displayed* (except on Windows where the native dialog used by `QFileDialog` does not display files when selecting folders).

Comment: ***please suggest some code snippet how to do this.*** Do you really want the user to select the folder or files containing zip files. Or do you want to get a list of all zip files in some fixed folder?

Comment: ***except on Windows where the native dialog used by QFileDialog does not display files when selecting folders*** That is where I have used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it displays just the folder name not with no files selected.

That is what it is supposed to return.  You asked it to display a dialog to select a folder, so that is all you can select.  `selectedFiles()` will return the path to the selected folder, per the documentation:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#FileMode-enum

> | Constant | Value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | QFileDialog::Directory | 2 | The name of a directory. Both files and directories are displayed. However, the native Windows file dialog does not support displaying files in the directory chooser. |

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#selectedFiles

> Returns a list of strings containing the absolute paths of the selected files in the dialog. If no files are selected, **or the mode is not `ExistingFiles` or `ExistingFile`, `selectedFiles()` contains the current path in the viewport**.

*After* the dialog has closed and `exec()` has returned, you will then need to iterate that folder yourself to discover `.zip` and `.7z` files in it.

An easier way to handle the dialog is to use [`QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory) instead.  You can construct a [`QDir`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) from the selected folder, and then use the [`QDir::entryList()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList) method to search for zip files in the folder.

See [How to read all files from a selected directory and use them one by one?](https://forum.qt.io/topic/64817/).

For example:

```
void MainWindow::on_browseButton_clicked()
{
    QDir directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this);
    QStringList zipFiles = directory.entryList(QStringList() << "*.zip" << "*.7z", QDir::Files);
    foreach(QString filename, zipFiles) {
        // do whatever you need to do
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I search for files recursively, meaning if a .zip file has another .zip file in it. Then how can I get he name of inner file.

Comment: You would have to open the `.zip` file and enumerate its contents.  That is outside the scope of this question. Post a separate question about that.